# Split string on commas ignoring commas, brackets, braces in parenthesis, quotes

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am attempting to split a comma separated list. I want to ignore commas that are in parenthesis, brackets, braces and quotes using regex. To be more precise I am trying to do this in postgres POSIX regexp_split_to_array.

My knowledge of regex is not great and by searching on stack overflow I was able to get a partial solution, I can split the string if it does not contain nested parenthesis, brackets, braces. Here is the regex:

```
,(?![^()]*+\))(?![^{}]*+})(?![^\[\]]*+\])(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

Test case:

```
0, (1,2), (1,2,(1,2)) [1,2,3,[1,2]], [1,2,3], "text, text (test)", {a1:1, a2:3, a3:{a1=1, s2=2}, a4:"asasad, sadsas, asasdasd"}
```

[Here is the demo](https://regex101.com/r/vAJ1Sa/3)

The problem is that in i.e. (1,2,(1,2)) the first 2 commas get matched if there is a nested parenthesis.

Comment: If that is possible at all, it would be quite difficult, so maybe the resulting regexp would not perform very well. Write a function in PL/Perl or another procedural language that does the job.

Comment: Regex is not the best tool to match nested constructs. However, if still needed, have a look at [Regular Expression Recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) or [Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Even though regex is not the best way to go, here is a solution with recursive matching:

```
(?>(?>\([^()]*(?R)?[^()]*\))|(?>\[[^[\]]*(?R)?[^[\]]*\])|(?>{[^{}]*(?R)?[^{}]*})|(?>"[^"]*")|(?>[^(){}[\]", ]+))(?>[ ]*(?R))*
```

If we break it down, there is a group with some stuff inside, followed by more of the same kind of matching, separated by optional spaces.

```
(?>               <---- start matching
   ...            <---- some stuff inside
)                 <---- end matching
(?>
   [ ]*           <---- optional spaces
   (?R)           <---- match the entire thing again
)*                <---- can be repeated
```

From your example `0, (1,2), (1,2,(1,2)) [1,2,3,[1,2]], [1,2,3],...`, we want to match:

```
0
(1,2)
(1,2,(1,2)) [1,2,3,[1,2]]
[1,2,3]
...
```

For the third match, the stuff inside will match `(1,2,(1,2))` and `[1,2,3,[1,2]]`, which are separated by a space.

The stuff inside is a series of options:

```
(?>
   (?>...)|       <---- will match balanced ()
   (?>...)|       <---- will match balanced []
   (?>...)|       <---- will match balanced {}
   (?>...)|       <---- will match "..."
   (?>...)        <---- will match anything else without space or comma
)
```

Here are the options:

```
\(                <---- literal (
  [^()]*          <---- any number of chars except ( or )
  (?R)?           <---- match the entire thing optionally
  [^()]*          <---- any number of chars except ( or )
\)                <---- literal )
```

```
\[                <---- literal [
  [^[\]]*         <---- any number of chars except [ or ]
  (?R)?           <---- match the entire thing optionally
  [^[\]]*         <---- any number of chars except [ or ]
\]                <---- literal ]
```

```
{                 <---- literal {
 [^{}]*           <---- any number of chars except { or }
 (?R)?            <---- match the entire thing optionally
 [^{}]*           <---- any number of chars except { or }
}                 <---- literal }
```

```
"                 <---- literal "
 [^"]*            <---- any number of chars except "
"                 <---- literal "
```

```
[^(){}[\]", ]+    <---- one or more chars except comma, or space, or these: (){}[]"
```

Note that this does not match a *comma-separated list*, but the items in such a list. The exclusion of comma and space in the last option above causes it to stop matching at comma or space (except for space we explicitly allowed between repeated matches).